# ¿Por qué cuando subo mi proyecto a internet las animaciones no funcionan?

Tags: javascript, ftp, cpanel

Tengo una web que al presionar sobre las secciones del menú te envía a dicho apartado con Javascript. En mi pc funciona perfecto pero en internet no; adjunto mi sitio para que puedan entender mejor (el problema sería en la barra superior donde al presionar Portfolio-Sobre Mí-Contacto debería enviarlos de manera suave y no tan brusca): https://francobuccieri.ml/

Comment: creo que se debe más a problema con las **rutas(absolutas o relativas)** a tus archivos css, agrega el código donde son importadas a tu index

Comment: Entra a tu página con cualquier Chrome/Firefox y pulsa F12. En la consola verás que los ficheros JS no se están cargando

Answer (score 0):

Estos dos archivos no se estan cargando

```
<!-- Contact form JS-->
<script src="assets/mail/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
<script src="assets/mail/contact_me.js"></script>
```

Revisa que esten en el servidor en las carpetas respectivas.
Estas url deberian mostrar el código javascript y no un error 404
https://francobuccieri.ml/assets/mail/contact_me.js y https://francobuccieri.ml/assets/mail/jqBootstrapValidation.js